# UISearchBar does not look properly

Tags: uisearchbar, ios5

Can't fix an issue with the subj on iPad with iOS 5. I create UISearchBar as usual:

```
UISearchBar *tempSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, fb.height-12, 309, 44)];
tempSearchBar.delegate = self;
tempSearchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
self.searchBar = tempSearchBar;
self.searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
[self.view addSubview:tempSearchBar];
```

but it doesn't look right.

[image]

The magnifuer glass is cut a little. I don't have UITextField categories `textRectForBounds`, `bounds` etc in my code.

Thanks in advance